# Capitalize First Letter of Last Name

Tags: java, capitalization

I want the last name to print with there first letter only capitalized but I get all of the last name capitalized. I want the user to input their name like Jordan Torres and give back Torres, J.

```
import java.util.*; // for Scanner

public class ProcessName { public static void main(String[] args) { String name;
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Type your name: "); //send to user

  name = console.nextLine();
     String[] nameArray = name.split(" ");//split string into array

     String firstName = name.valueOf(name.charAt(0)).toUpperCase(); //get first letter 
     String lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" ") + 1).toUpperCase();

     String myName = lastName + ", " + firstName;//give last and first name

       System.out.println("Your name is: " + myName + ".");
```

My output is TORRES, J.

Comment: So what's the problem? If you want it not to be `TORRES` and instead `Torres` then just apply `.toUpperCase()` to the first letter, you are applying it to the entire sub string.

Comment: I only want the first letter of the last name to be Capitalized not the whole thing.

Comment: right okay, then what if they just put torres without a capital t? then its just torres. how can I make it so the first letter is always capitalized for the last name?

Comment: Then do `.toUpperCase()` for the first letter, and `.toLowerCase()` for the rest.

Comment: how would I go about doing that? I don't know how to split between doing .toUpperCase then to .toLowerCase()

Comment: @Jordan There's this great thing called [Google](http://google.com).

Comment: @Qix yea didn't think of that before... Really man give me a break jeeze.

Comment: @Jordan we see thousands of questions on SO a day that usually can be solved by Googling. Apologies for taking the time to comment on each one. :)

Comment: Be aware that this makes a presumption of only two names. If someone has three or more, it will presume that the last name behind on the second one.

Comment: Right, I just need only two names as of now, but will need to change that in a later time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Get the last name as entered by the user
String lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" ") + 1);

// Upcase the first character, then append the remaining characters
lastName = Character.toUpperCase(lastName.charAt(0)) + lastName.substring(1);
```

Comment: Alright my man, thank you very much. That is what I needed. I understand now.